# Standard Time Zone Names/IDs

Tags: .net, objective-c, timezone, standards

Are there standardized time zone names that are recognized by different operating systems and/or platforms?  For example, it doesn't look like the strings returned by `[NSTimeZone knownTimeZones]` in Objective C match the IDs returned by `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` in .NET.  Am I going to have to write conversion tables if I want to recognize time zones between systems?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about other systems but in .NET you can get the GetUtcOffset for a numerical offset from UTC.

Comment: That has to be paired with a date, though, right?  If it's paired with a timezone then you can't figure out if/when/how it changes to DST.

Comment: What I think you would need to do is compare a date in daylight saving and a date not in daylight savings.  If both match then I think you can conclude it is the same time zone.   If this does not work please let me know and I will delete the answer.